# Is there a quick way to do multiple : Select > Same > Fill & Stroke and group

Tags: script

I am working on many designs and the job i have been given is to change the colours but all designs have lots of colours so i need to select all the colours and group them.
After 100 designs and 35 colours in each design - i hope to find a quicker way.

Does anyone know any quicker way please?

Comment: The reason you fail to get answers is is as follows: 1. Your asking to do work for you, this allways leads to a bad taste in mouth. Even though ultimately 90% of questions do probably have the same ultimate goal they arent as open about it it makes a huge difference 2. Ultimately, we do not know what you want to achieve for all we know this us a XY problem that leads to more questions down the line. Present your problem instead not your solution. We know your solution is weak, you wouldnt be asking otherwise. 3. Show us what you know, its hard to answer in information vacuum.

Comment: So that's your attitude Joojaa. Dont judge as i help out a huge amount of people in life. I may have lost my family business and had to take a job that i know very little about. My ultimate goal is to get some help - i'm not asking people to do programming for me, im not asking people to go out of their way - f someone has a script then it would take them no time to share it. If there are quick keys then again it won't take long. Sorry for not being as clever as you at these things but im not sorry i don't have your attitude.

Comment: I didnt downvite or close vote. I was just pointing out how to get most of the stackexchange site. This is a much better question than your first one. But still you probably wont get the perfect answer untill you work out what the goal for doing this is. The only reason i didnt amswer your scripting question is that i know that grouping destroys the look and feel of most arwork so just blindly doing this is unlikely to be useful even if you say so. ON the otherhand you may actually want to do a color separation which can be done done in the print dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need a script for this. If you are using Adobe Illustrator, you could record an Action, and set a Function key to run it.  Then all you'd need to do is select one item, and hit the function key.  Obviously, this is only semi-automated in that you'd still need to make a selection, but it is quick. If you have lots of colours, then a script might be a better way to do it. Sadly, not within my abilities.

Anyway here's an example

[image]

Then record your action

[image]

Here it is being used

[image]

Comment: so great - thank yo usb much for your time sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @NehaSharma For my purposes, which this is needed often, I simply assigned a shortcut to the select same command via `Edit > keyboard Shortcuts`. I can then just select something hold the CMD key and hit F1, then G... So it's 2 key presses rather than 1, but it also allows me to use the F1 shortcut *without* grouping things. (+1) An Action will work well though.